# JFileChooser with Windows7 look and feel missing buttons

Tags: java, windows-7, look-and-feel

I succeeded in creating a `JFileChooser` in the windows look and feel with the following code

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {     }
```

But when the JFileChooser comes up, it is missing buttons to the right of the drop-down menu of file names. The buttons that are missing are the up one level, create new Folder, list view, and details view buttons.

Any ideas on how I can get them back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a particular problem with my computer - when I run this program on other computers, the buttons appear. Go figure.

Comment: make sure you are using exactly the same version of the java runtime environment on both PCs

Comment: Ewwww, I having exactly the same issue... I am on Win 7 32 bits running Netbeans. Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`JFileChooser` isn't a native dialog.  In fact, nothing in Swing is.

If you want native controls and dialogs, you need to use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) instead of Swing.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with JRE 1.6.0 update 18. Apparently, this is a bug: [Bug ID: 6840086 JFileChooser lacks icons on top right when running on Windows 7](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=9f5cc75b48ec6ffffffffff524f8e85dab2e?bug_id=6840086).

This bug has been fixed in the latest version of JRE: 1.6.0 update 22.

Comment: I still see it in JRE: 1.6.0_24-b07

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no exceptions spitted out ? Perhaps put a e.printStackTrace() in the catch block just to be 100% sure that there are no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The issue still happens on 1.6_0.25-b06. I have created a [thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2231174) on Oracle's forum.

**ADDITION**

I had this issue because NetBeans was pointing to JDK 1.6.13 directory. I had to install JDK 1.6.25 and update netbean's config file + reboot NetBeans.